# Use Python's easy_install in intranet

Tags: python, easy-install

Increasingly I found myself using tools based upon python, particularly that use installation processes involving easy_install.  The trouble for me is that I am

1. On an intranet with no internet access
2. On windows (which always complicates things a little!)

Any advice on how to setup easy_install on my intranet to make using python based tools a bit easier?

Comment: Wouldn't having no internet access prevent you from accessing the packages at all? Are you planning to get the packages by some other means, and then put them somewhere on your intranet?

Comment: I could physically transfer the eggs from the internet to the intranet (USB Key, special account, etc.).  It would be nice to have them in one place so that any intranet user can access them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use .egg files with easy_install, you could host those on your intranet and point easy_install to it. See http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/EasyInstall#using-easy-install for a good reference.

Comment: Thanks, looks like the -f option may be what I'm looking for as a short term solution.